# How can I get around 54 levels of nesting in excel

Tags: excel

I like to add 54 of the IF nesting I tried adding & option by breaking these up after every 8 as i have done it only allows extra 8 more nesting then the rest don't work that it. Is there any way I can get around this for this to work?

`=IF(E9<231,"1",IF(E9<321,"2",IF(E9<411,"3",IF(E9<501,"4",IF(E9<591,"5",IF(E9<681,"6",IF(E9<771,"7",IF(E9<861,"8",)))))))))IF(E9<951,"9",IF(E9<1041,"10",IF(E9<1131,"11",IF(E9<1221,"12",IF(E9<1311,"13",IF(E9<1401,"14",IF(E9<1491,"15",IF(E9<1581,"16",))))))))IF(E9<1581,"16",IF(E9<1671,"17",IF(E9<1761,"18",IF(E9<1851,"19",IF(E9<1941,"20",IF(E9<2031,"21",IF(E9<2121,"22",)))))))IF(E9<2211,"23",IF(E9<2301,"24",IF(E9<2391,"25",IF(E9<2481,"26",IF(E9<2571,"27",IF(E9<2661,"28",IF(E9<2751,"29",IF(E9<2841,"30",)))))))) IF(E9<2931,"31", IF(E9<3021,"32", IF(E9<3111,"33",IF(E9<3201,"34", IF(E9<3291,"35", IF(E9<3381,"36", IF(E9<3471,"37", IF(E9<3561,"38",)))))))) IF(E9<3651,"39", IF(E9<3741,"40", IF(E9<3831,"41", IF(E9<3921,"42", IF(E9<4011,"43", IF(E9<4101,"44", IF(E9<4191,"45", IF(E9<4281,"46",)))))))) IF(E9<4371,"47", IF(E9<4461,"48", IF(E9<4551,"49", IF(E9<4641,"50", IF(E9<4731,"51", IF(E9<4821,"52", IF(E9<4911,"53", IF(E9<5001,"54",)))))))`

Comment: Please format your code properly and use the proper formatting tools provided by stack overflow, so that people can easily understand your code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri The answer shows it has been understood...

Comment: Ah i see. I got it for reviewing and i thought it was poorly formatted, but i was not sure. That is why i left a comment. Note that even though it might be understood, it is always better to format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested functions sometimes have patterns that can be exploited with some maths.

```
=INT(MAX(E9-51,90)/90)
```

You offered no provision for valies in column E being greater than 5000 but that could easily be added.

Comment: Hi Jeeped this one works but i got no idea HOW!! you did this but then how will it work for another cell it just as same but the number is different see here:231-2, 321-3, 411-4, 501-5, 591-6, 681-7, 771-8 and so on the final one is 5001-55 just like the previous just the number is higher.

Comment: If the lowest comparison is still <231 and the pattern (step 90) is still the same but the result should should be 1 higher, add +1 to the end. There are other methods like +(column(a:a)-1) or +(row(1:1)-1) if you want to drag the original formula right or down.

Comment: Thank you my friend you have saved me :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use MATCH()

```
=MATCH(E9,{0,231,321,411,501,...})
```

Replace the `...` with the rest of your thresholds.

As @SolarMike stated you can also put the thresholds in a range.  Then refer to that range instead of "hardcoding " the array.  So if you put your threshold in A1:A55 the formula would be:

```
=MATCH(E9,A1:A55)
```

Comment: Using a defined range ie list may offer an easily editable option in this case... but much better than the if statements... I thought my 7 or 8 levels was pushing it but this takes the award... :)

Comment: That was quick scott i have been on this for days you might have solved this in seconds!! okay so on your first which is =MATCH(E9,{0,231,321,411,501}) do i need to put all the rest of the values like this =match(E9,{0,231,321,411,501 and so on until the last value 5001 at the end. so how does it know which number to display in between the sizes say the first if it is 321it should display 3. How does it know!!

Comment: its like this so if i inter a number higher then 232 it should return with number 2 links and if i was to inter 415 then it should display 4 links needed so the 231 is the width and other numbers are links i would need for that width. i hope this help.
231-1,
321-2,
411-3,
501-4,
591-5,
681-6,
771-7,

Comment: @P.Badwell you will need to enter all your thresholds.